# Trabalhando com array com X camadas em JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, array-multidimensional, programação-dinâmica

Estou com um grande problema, já pesquisei em diversos lugares e não achei a solução espero que vocês possam me ajudar...
Meu objetivo é criar uma função em JS que vai pegar um array como base, que aqui vou chamar de "**A**" a estrutura dele é essa:

```
var A = {
        a1: {
            c1: 50,
            c2: 50,
        },
        b1: {
            d1: 0,
            d2: [1 => "hello"],
            d3: [2 => "world"],
        }
    };
```

A função vai receber outro array, que vou chamar de "**B**", segue a estrutura dele:

```
var B = {
        a1: {
            c1: 1,
            c2: 125,
        },
    };
```

Após o array "**B**" passar pela função ele deve "sair" com a estrutura idêntica ao do "**A**" e com os valores que faltava no "**B**" idênticos ao do "**A**", ou seja:

Array "**B**" após passar pela função:

```
var B = {
        a1: { /* índice que já existia no array "B" */
            c1: 1, /* índice e valor que já existia no array "B" */
            c2: 125, /* índice e valor que já existia no array "B" */
        },
        b1: { /* índice que NÂO existia no array "B" e como o array "A" é a base foi criado esse índice no array "B" */
            d1: 0, /* índice e valor que não existia no array "B", é a mesma história do b1 aqui em cima */
            d2: [1 => "hello"], /* mesmo caso dos outros dois acima */
            d3: [2 => "world"], /* mesmo caso dos outros três acima */
        }
    };
```

Digamos que até ai tudo bem, minha grande questão é, eu tenho o array "**A**" como base, quando eu querer modificar a estrutura do "**A**" digamos adicionar mais um nível nele como no exemplo:

```
var A2 = {
        a1: {
            c1: 50,
            c2: 50,
        },
        b1: {
            d1: 0,
            d2: [e1 => "hello"],
            d3: [
                   f2 => "world",
                   f3 => [
                            g1 => "nova",
                            g2 => "camada"
                         ]
                ],
        }
    };
```

Do jeito que eu imaginei até agora esse script iria dar erro se eu fizesse isso e é óbvio que eu não quero que isso aconteça, o que eu realmente quero é que o array "**B**" ao passar pela função, também receba a nova camada...

Já comecei a fazer esse código porém não consigo terminar por causa dessa maldita dúvida.
Código que já desenvolvi http://jsfiddle.net/mateusfmello/mja8ffs2/7/

Comment: Olá Mateus! Acho que estás a chamar aray a objetos. Esta sintax `d2: [e1 => "hello"],` não é de JavaScript. Queres dizer `d2: {e1: "hello"},`?

Comment: Exatamente, vou corrigir... Obrigado pela observação... Você sabe como eu posso resolver essa questão?

Comment: Agora me veio outra questão, o que usar? arrays ou objetos? o que vc sugere?

Comment: Para o exemplo que tens parece-me que objetos é melhor. Vou então dar uma olhada e já comento. Uma pergunta: esses objetos têm só strings e numeros dentro deles? ou elementos do DOM e outros?

Comment: Pode ter números, strings e objetos... A grande questão é o objetos... Você chegou a dar uma olhada no código que esta no jsfiddle?

Comment: Sim, ví o jsFiddle. Já vou responder (se ninguém fôr mais rápido que eu) mas queria saber mais informação para dar a resposta certa.

Comment: Ultima pergunta: dizes "Pode ter números, strings e objetos" eu queria saber se esses objetos têm algo do DOM?

Comment: Não vai conter, porém vai resultar gráficos em canvas... os dados que vai ser passado para a função é os dados do canvas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma parte importante é usares uma função que tenha um interface claro. Ou seja essa função deve ter como função/ordem comparar o que lhe é dado e mais nada.

Assim sugiro algo assim:

```
function completarObjetos(original, aCompletar) {
    function dup(o) {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));
    };

    for (var key in original) {
        var obj = original[key];
        var aC = aCompletar[key];
        if (aC) {
            if (dup(aC) == dup(obj)) continue;
            else aCompletar[key] = completarObjetos(obj, aC);
        } else {
            aCompletar[key] = dup(obj);
        }
    }
    return aCompletar;
}
```

Usando a lógica da função `dup()` podes clonar partes internas do objeto *original* e também comparar objetos via sua representação *string* poupando mais iterações nos sub-objetos de cada um quando isso não é necessário.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m4jqcvx0/1/

Comment: Sergio, `aC = completarObjetos(obj, aC);` não deveria ser `aCompletar[key] = completarObjetos(obj, aC);`?

Comment: @falsarella eu estava a pensar em objetos que no caso passariam por referência. Mas podem ser strings... bem visto, obrigado. Corrigi.

Comment: Cara é isso ai mesmo, vlw, funcionou certinho... eu sou novo por aqui, e minha reputação é baixa, mas assim que tiver mais de 15 eu volto e dou um voto na tua resposta...

Comment: @MateusFernandesdeMello ótimo que ajudou. Bemvindo! Se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite. Independentemente da reputação.

Comment: Blz, já marquei...

Answer (score 0):

Em determinadas estruturas dos objetos a função entrava em loop infinito, devido isso fiz uma pequena alteração e venho compartilhar com vocês

Em

```
 else aC = completarObjetos(obj, aC);
```

eu adicionei a seguinte verificação `else if (typeof obj == "object") aC = comple...` dessa forma não ocorre mais o loop infinito.

Como ocorria o loop infinito? Quando o `for (var key in original) {` terminava de percorrer toda estrutura assim chegando no último valor, a variável `key` virava uma string com o valor 0 (zero) e com isso toda vez que passava na verificação `if (dup(aC) == dup(obj))` dava como `false`, pois `aC` retornava M, pois `var aC = aCompletar[0];` sendo assim pegava a primeira letra do nome Mateus e `obj` retornava w, pois `var obj = original[0];` sendo assim pegava a primeira letra do nome world, lembrando que isso ocorria no **último** loop, estando em

```
 d3: {
     2: "world"
 },
```

e como a verificação `if (dup(aC) == dup(obj))` retornava false o código executado era o `else aCompletar[key] = completarObjetos(obj, aC);` assim chamando milhares de vezes a mesma função e ocorrendo a mesma coisa sempre.

Códigos: http://jsfiddle.net/mateusfmello/m4jqcvx0/4/

Remova `if (typeof obj == "object")` da linha 44 e agora adicione

```
console.log(key);
console.log(typeof key);
```

na linha 38, abra o console do seu browser (F12), execute o código clicando em "Run" e observe o erro...

Answer (score 0):

acabei de achar o que eu queria, `$.extend(true, param1, param2);`, porém depende do jQuery.

Funciona da seguinte forma, o `true` informa que queremos adicionar os dados do `param2` no `param1` de forma recursiva, como já podemos observar parece que `param2` tem todos os dados e em `param1` que poderia estar faltando, mas não é bem assim,  o `param1` seria o objeto que você tem todos os dados seria no caso o default, por tanto, o `param2` é o parâmetro que ira passar novos dados, ou então personalizar os dados do `param1`.

Espero que gostem :D

Documentação: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/